# Is apoc.rel.startNode removed from apoc 4.2.0.0?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have neo4j 4.2.1 & apoc 4.2.0.0 installed on my mac. When I run the example on https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.rel/apoc.rel.startNode/ in neo4j desktop, I get the following error:
Unknown function 'apoc.rel.startNode' (line 4, column 8 (offset: 204))
"RETURN apoc.rel.startNode(rel) AS startNode"

I am able to successfully run the example on https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.rel/apoc.rel.type/

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade apoc to 4.2.0.4 it should be back

Answer (score 1):

In 4.x, APOC core procs/functions are bundled with Neo4j and can be moved from the labs folder to the plugins folder for installation. It's possible that the function in question wasn't included in this core library.

You can look for and download the appropriate full version of APOC here, that will include functions and procedures beyond what is contained in the APOC core library.

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases

Make sure you remove the existing jar when you add in the full jar, as if you try to start up with both in the plugins folder you'll encounter errors.